# CMD Command Line: One command plus direct output of the ERRORLEVEL into a TXT?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, output, errorlevel

CMD Command Line:
One CMD command, one command row, no BAT file.

Is there a chance to get the ERRORLEVEL directly written in a TXT file?

I tried but I failed.

I don't want to create and save a BAT file each time.

I would prefer the simpler way: CMD single command plus export of the ERRORLEVEL in a TXT file, all in one command line.

Tommy

Comment: Please rewrite your question to an understandable state. I barely get what you want, except for writing  the `errorlevel` into a file and that you fail with batch-files. In that case I suggest showing said batch-file(s) or what you are having problems with and carify a bit :)

Comment: "I don't want to create and save a BAT file."
Is this difficult to understand ? :-)
I want to execute many CMD commands "on-the-fly".
So creating many BAT files is not the best way ... I think so.
In each case it is only one command. And I need the errorlevel (there are 5 or 6 integer values I could get as the result).

Comment: Then **don't** create and **don't** save a batch-file! Boom that easy! But I guess that has not been your question... You got a few ways to go here: Type stuff everytime you need it into the command-prompt, create a batch-file for double-click usage or store one-line commands in an environment variable for quicker use.

Answer (score 4):

This, the usual first idea, will fail

```dos
( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" echo %errorlevel%
```

The problem is that the full command line is parsed and then executed. During the parse phase all the variable read operations are removed from the command being replaced with the value stored inside the variables before starting to execute the command.

This means that a single line can not change a variable and retrieve the changed value as there are not any read operation in the executed command.

***note***: while not this case, this parse/replace behaviour affect a full line when read, but also to all the lines inside a block, that is, all the lines enclosed in parenthesis. When execution reaches a block of code all the lines in the block are read, all variable read operations inside the block are replaced and then the execution of the resulting command(s) starts.

The real executed command is (supossing errorlevel is 0 before execution)

```dos
( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" echo 0
```

The usual way to deal with it is to enable delayed expansion. This allows you to change where need the syntax used to access a variable from `%var%` into `!var!`. This indicates to the parser that the variable/value substitution must be delayed until the command is executed, not when the line is parsed. This is done with the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command.

But, this command has no effect in command line, only on batch files. In command line, it is necessary to start the `cmd` instance with `/v` switch to enable delayed expansion. If you start your `cmd` instance with delayed expansion you can use

```dos
( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" echo !errorlevel!
```

But with delayed expansion enabled, `!` in commands becames a problem as the parser will see it as part of a variable read request.

You have another alternative. You can write the command in a way that the variable gets not replaced at parse time and then, at execute time force a new parse of the command

```dos
( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" call echo %^errorlevel%
```

With the `^` the variable is not recognized, and the command is parsed and executed as

```dos
( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" call echo %errorlevel%
```

Then, when the `call` command is executed a new parse phase is invoked and then, after the first command has been executed and the `errorlevel` has changed, the variable is replaced in the line and the correct value is sent to the file.

**edited** to adapt to comments - Just a test session (sorry, spanish locale)

```
W:\41996740>dir /b

W:\41996740>( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" call echo %^errorlevel%
"commandToExecute" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

W:\41996740>dir /b
file.txt

W:\41996740>type file.txt
9009

W:\41996740>( dir /b file.txt ) & >"file.txt" call echo %^errorlevel%
file.txt

W:\41996740>type file.txt
0

W:\41996740>( dir /b file.exe ) & >"file.txt" call echo %^errorlevel%
No se encuentra el archivo

W:\41996740>type file.txt
1

W:\41996740>
```

Comment: Impressive. I did not get what OP wanted... Good explanation!

Comment: Hi,I need exactly this: ( commandToExecute ) & echo %errorlevel%>"file.txt"
But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Donny73Ger, No, you don't need it, as you point it doesn't work. You need `( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" call echo %^errorlevel%`

Comment: ( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" call echo %^errorlevel% ... result (content of the txt file) is "ECHO ist eingeschaltet (ON)." ... and not the error level value.

Comment: @Donny73Ger, see updated answer. Tested and working. Check that you have not defined the value for the `errorlevel` variable, execute first `set "errorlevel="` to ensure it is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using [enabled Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (see `/V:ON` switch), just for completeness:

```
cmd /D /V:ON /C "command to execute&>>currError.txt echo !errorlevel!"
```

**Examples** (output to `currError.txt` is extended to contain date and time stamp in addition to bare `errorlevel`):

```
==> type currError.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.

==> cmd /D /V:ON /C "echox "x"&>>currError.txt echo %date% %time% errorlevel !errorlevel!"
'echox' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

==> type currError.txt
02.02.2017  9:12:28,34 errorlevel 9009

==> cmd /D /V:ON /C "echo "x"&>>currError.txt echo %date% %time% errorlevel !errorlevel!"
"x"

==> type currError.txt
02.02.2017  9:12:28,34 errorlevel 9009
02.02.2017  9:12:43,32 errorlevel 0

==> rem output fails if "command to execute" is syntactically wrong

==> cmd /D /V:ON /C "if "x"&>currError.txt echo %date% %time% errorlevel !errorlevel!"
& was unexpected at this time.

==> type currError.txt
02.02.2017  9:12:28,34 errorlevel 9009
02.02.2017  9:12:43,32 errorlevel 0

==> rem "call" approach for the sake of completeness:

==> echox "x"&>>currError.txt call echo %date% %time% errorlevel %errorlevel^%
'echox' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

==> type currError.txt
02.02.2017  9:12:28,34 errorlevel 9009
02.02.2017  9:12:43,32 errorlevel 0
02.02.2017 14:42:28,06 errorlevel 9009

==> rem fails as well if "command to execute" is syntactically wrong

==> if "x"&>>currError.txt call echo %date% %time% errorlevel %errorlevel^%
& was unexpected at this time.

==> type currError.txt
02.02.2017  9:12:28,34 errorlevel 9009
02.02.2017  9:12:43,32 errorlevel 0
02.02.2017 14:42:28,06 errorlevel 9009

==>
```

Comment: This works:

cmd /von /c "call ( commandToExecute )&>"file.txt" echo !errorlevel!

Answer (score 0):

First, define a "p" variable with a percent-sign:

```
set "p=%"
```

Then, use this line:

```
( commandToExecute ) & >"file.txt" call echo %p%errorlevel%p%
```

Tested on Windows 8.1